# R data not being plotted correctly

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot, dplyr

I'm really struggling with plots in R with ggplot and dplyr.

I have a dataframe with columns:

```
Customer.Name, Customer.Code, Product, Date, Platform, Input.Records, Output.Records
```

I performed a grouping with dplyr, to group the input records by the date.

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
dateGrouping <- df%>% group_by(`Date`) %>% summarise(`Input.Records` = sum(`Input.Records`))
```

Then I tried to plot that.

```
myPlot <- ggplot(data=dateGrouping, aes(x=factor(Date), y=`Input.Records`, group=1)) +
  geom_line() + ylim(0, 85000000)
myPlot
```

But the output looks wrong, it looks like a bar plot, there is no connection between the lines
[image: The "Line" plot]

So I swapped `geom_line()` with `geom_path()`
[image]

And this definitely looks wrong...why is the path going back and forth? it should be a left-to-right linear trajectory shouldn't it?

This is the code to replicate the example. Including only the code for the grouped frame because the full file is too large and contains confidential data.

```
   library(ggplot2) 
   library(dplyr) 
   df <- data.frame("Date" = c( "2020-08-10", "2020-08-11", "2020-08-12", "2020-08-13", "2020-08-14", "2020-08-15", "2020-08-16", "2020-08-17", "2020-08-18",
 "2020-08-19", "2020-08-20", "2020-08-21", "2020-08-22", "2020-08-23", "2020-08-24"),
 "Input.Records" = c(19501675,19298520,75546425,90104271,34139598,35384083,11849216,21996019,241643844,55643434,20733736,46198249,9815057,78211864,103263783))
    
    myPlot <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=factor(Date), y=`Input.Records`, group=1)) +
      geom_path() + ylim(0, 85000000)
    myPlot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. I made some slight changes to your code:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Plot
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Date, y=Input.Records, group=1)) +
  geom_line()
```

Output:

[image]

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: This is indeed the output that I want, but what changes did you do? The code looks identical minus the removal of factor() and backticks.

Comment: @Elmambo2194 Just remove the limits you set on y-axis and try plotting, I believe that should alleviate the issue! As you see, the line is created perfectly!

Comment: Thank you, it did work. If I use limits I get the message `Warning message:
Removed 1 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).`. Is there any reason for that?
Also, it's fine if I need another question, but is there a way to have the Y labels display as numbers like 80,000,000 rather than scientific notation?

Comment: @Elmambo2194 When you see that rows are removed is because of the limits. One row must be outside the limits and then is removed. For what you said you can add `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)` after your `geom_line()` so it should be `geom_line()+scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)` and thanks to you too!